# Oracle trigger to update an entity in different table

Tags: oracle, triggers

So this is from a uni coursework and is my first time working with Oracle (and using triggers). We are supposed to be creating a database for an airlines.

Part of the database is

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_BOOKING (
  BOOKING_ID NUMBER(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  BOOKING_TIME DATE NOT NULL,
  EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
  FLIGHT_ID NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
  TOTAL_COST NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT (
  FLIGHT_ID NUMBER(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  PLANE_ID NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
  START_ID NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
  DESTINATION_ID NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
  TRANSIT_ID NUMBER(11),
  DEPARTURE_TIME DATE NOT NULL,
  ARRIVAL_TIME DATE NOT NULL,
  NUM_BOOKED NUMBER (4) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PASSENGER (
  PASSENGER_ID NUMBER(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NULL,
  LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  TELEPHONE NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
  BOOKING_ID NUMBER(11) NOT NULL
);
```

So what I want to do is create a trigger such that every time a new passenger is added to the PASSENGER table, the trigger finds the corresponding FLIGHT_ID from the FLIGHT_BOOKING table and increments NUM_BOOKED for the corresponding flight in the FLIGHT table.

I have tried going through the oracle documentation, but i could not find anything that describes a situation where two or more tables are concerned.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_flight_booking_info
  AFTER INSERT ON PASSENGER
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    v_flight_id number;
    v_booking_id number;
BEGIN
    v_booking_id  := :new.booking_id ;

    select flight_id into v_flight_id
    from flight_booking
    where booking_id = v_booking_id;

    update flight
    set NUM_BOOKED = NUM_BOOKED + 1
    where flight_id = v_flight_id;
END;
```

HTH.

Comment: No need for the separate select. You can do it in one update.

Comment: @GolezTrol: yes, you're absolutely right. Tks.
I've just wanted to demonstrate the solution step by step, that maybe make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather *not* store that number, and calculate it as needed, but okay, it is just course material. :)

When you create a trigger, inside it you can put all kinds of code, including update statements.

So you can write a trigger like this:

```
create or replace trigger TIDB_BOOKING
before insert or delete
for each row
declare
  V_Increment int;
begin
  -- Inc or dec, depending on insert or update.
  -- Hasn't a booking got a number of seats?
  -- Also, can bookings be updated/moved to other flights?
  -- These problems aren't yet taken into account in this code.
  V_Increment := 1; 
  if deleting then
    V_Increment := -1;

  update FLIGHT f
  set f.NUM_BOOKED = f.NUM_BOOKED + V_Increment
  where f.FLIGHT_ID = nvl(:new.FLIGHT_ID, :old.FLIGHT_ID);
end;
```